# Two toolbars showing up in Navigation Drawer in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am trying to show a particular `ToolBar` in a `Fragment` that is connected through `NavigationDrawer`.

I have `NavigationDrawer` extends `AppCompatActivity` this has a particular `ToolBar` showing up properly.

Now I would kike to show another toolbar which has drop down etc. When I click on the `Fragment`, this one is also coming fine but with the old toolbar. How do I hide the `Toolbar` which is showing the old one?

See the snapshot below:

[image]

Like above instead of Toolbar title I would like **Rediff/Dropdown** toolbar to come up there?

So how do I hide old `ToolBar` and show the new one?
Toolbar with Spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is what I have in Fragment:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (hideToolBar)
        {
            ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
        else
        {
            ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
        }


        if (mToolbar != null)
        {
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        }

        navSpinner = new ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem>();
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.all)));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.week)));
        navSpinner.add(new SpinnerNavItem(getResources().getString(R.string.month)));

        adapter = new NavigationAdapter(getActivity(),  navSpinner);
        mSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: hide that toolbar when you are launching the fragment

Comment: select the no action bar theme in AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: @user3459071: I am already using No actionbar theme. It is already showing a toolbar and hence two toolbar is coming up.

Comment: @NileshJarad: how do I hide toolbar?

Comment: @NileshJarad: If I do hide - I will not get the Navigation Drawer the three horizontal line. How do I get that?

Comment: can post your toolbar layout xml and source code so i can help out with that

Comment: Sure. I can will put them both. Can you please tell me what you want on source code? Fragment source code or the Navigation Drawer's source code?

Comment: @NileshJarad : I have put the toolbar code and fragment code. Let me know if you require anything exta. Thanks!

Comment: @SanjanaNair for activity you are using same `ToolBar` or different `ToolBar`

Comment: @NileshJarad: For Activity I am using different toolbar.  For fragment different

Comment: @SanjanaNair I have posted answer check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same `ToolBar`for `Activity`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:visibility="GONE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In your `Activity` getReference to `Spinner`

When you launch `Fragment` make `Spinner`  **VISIBLE/GONE**

i.e

```
getActivity().spinnerInMainActivity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: That is good idea. will try this out and let you know the outcome. 

Can you also help me with the following issue: I have added the toolbar with the spinner like yours... I would like to add an ImageView to the right? Even after I add wrap content to spinner it is taking full space and hence ImageView is not showing up...

Comment: Put linear layout inside toolbar and then place other elements in that

Comment: Will try and let you know!